# What does IDEA use to determine the application to open a file with?

Tags: intellij-idea

In *Settings > Editor > File Types* there is an item "Files Opened In Associated Applications" which is, as far as I understand, used to specify which files should be opened with an external application rather than in editor in IDEA. How are file associations configured? This doesn't seem to use `xdg-open` as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 5):

**Settings > Editor > File Types > "Files Opened In Associated Applications"** lets you view and modify file type mappings, but there's no way to specify a link to an external editor there.

The approach for specifying an external editor for a file type differs slightly depending on whether IDEA already knows about the file type.

If you want to specify an external editor in IDEA for an unknown file type (e.g. **zzz**):

- Create a file in your project. e.g. **test.zzz**

[image: assoc1]

- Idea will invite you register a new file type association. Select the option "**Open matching files in associated application**" then click **OK** to close that window.

[image: assoc2]

- Double click the file to open it. Since IDEA doesn't know how to open that file it asks you...

[image: assoc3]

- Click **More apps**, then scroll down to select your external editor. I chose Notepad.

[image: assoc4]

- After that, IDEA will use Notepad to open files of type **zzz**.

However, if IDEA already knows about the file type you first need to remove the existing association. For example, if you want to use Notepad instead of Idea to edit Kotlin files of type **.kts**, go to **Settings > Editor > File Types**, scroll down to select **Kotlin**, select ***.kts** from the **Registered Patterns** then click the Minus button to remove the existing association:

[image: assoc5]

After that, the process for mapping ***.kts** files is the same as for mapping an unknown file type as described above.

(I'm using Windows so the process for selecting the external editor
might be slightly different on Mac or Linux.)